# ASP.net VB.net How to call Microsoft Cognitive Service - Web Search

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, azure-cognitive-services

I've been playing around with this for hours and I'm a little stuck. Have been unable to find a good tutorial. I'm trying to use Microsoft Cognitive services to get web search results.

I think I might be on the correct tract with my request but I have no idea how to call the request and parse the json results. Any help would be super appreciated.

What I have so far:

```
        Dim bingSearchUrl As String = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search/"
        Dim client  = HttpClientFactory.Create()
        Dim queryString = bingSearchUrl & "?q=" & searchString & "&count=10"

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("offset", "0")
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("mkt", "en-us")
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("safesearch", "Moderate")
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "mykey")
        Dim r As String = client.GetStringAsync(queryString).ToString 

        MsgBox(r)
```

Comment: What problem are you facing? Couple of things I noticed are: You need to `await` the `async` operation making the function `async` as specified [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156570.aspx). You can use [Newtonsoft JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) JSON library to de-serialize the string.

Comment: Problem is I don't know how to get results. I will read the links you suggested. Thanks.